# Right aligning an element within absolute positioned heading

Tags: html, css

I have some css to keep the headings in a table fixed while the body can be scrolled. I have a problem when I want to right-align some of the columns; because the heading is using divs with absolute positioning I can't work out how to right-align the text within it. I have to admit to struggling with CSS. I copied this code from a solution somewhere on the web that I now can't find again and I don't entirely understand it. For the most part it works really well so I'd love to find out how to fix the headings.

.css:

```css
.panel
{
    overflow:auto; 
    overflow-x:hidden;
    border: solid 1px #838383;
}

.fixedTableContainer {
    height: 320px;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    background-color: white;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 20px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
}

.fixedTableContainerInner {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 24px;
}

.fixedTableContainerInner th {
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.thInner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: -5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font: normal normal 10pt Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<asp:Panel runat="server" id="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="panel">
    <asp:ListView runat="server" id="listView" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CompanyAccountID">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div class="fixedTableContainer">
                <div class="fixedTableContainerInner">
                    <table style="width: 100%">
                        <tr>
                            <th><div class="thInner">Acct. ID</div></th>
                            <th><div class="thInner">Account Name</div></th>
                            <th><div class="thInner right">Account Code</div></th>
                            <th><div class="thInner">Sort Code</div></th>
                            <th><div class="thInner">Account Number</div></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr id="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        
        
    </asp:ListView>
</asp:Panel>
```

I want to be able to right-align any of those heading with respect to their container div but everything I've tried seems to either have no effect or to align the text right with respect to a higher container - I didn't really notice if it was the table or the form. Any help much appreciated.

NB: I have edited this from the original to include more detail as the first solutions suggested didn't work for me.

Thanks all.

PS. After much searching I finally found the original post that I got the code from: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dPixie/byB9d/3/light/)

Comment: Thanks for the rapid responses and apologies for taking so long to respond. I've been firefighting a horrible SharePoint application. Sadly, none of these ideas worked. I think it must be connected to the code that wraps this so I'll update the question with more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. It works.

```css
.thInner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    line-height: 24px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    text-align: right;
    margin-left: -5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font: normal normal 10pt Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.thInner.c1 {
   left:-80%;
}
.thInner.c2 {
  left:-60%;
}
.thInner.c3 {
  left:-40%;
}
.thInner.c4 {
  left:-20%;
}
.thInner.c5 {
  left:0;
}
```

```html
        <table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th><div class="thInner c1">Acct. ID</div></th>
                <th><div class="thInner c2">Account Name</div></th>
                <th><div class="thInner c3">Account Code</div></th>
                <th><div class="thInner c4">Sort Code</div></th>
                <th><div class="thInner c5">Account Number</div></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work when you add a width to the columns.
For example:
`<th><div class="thInner" style="widht: 100px; text-align: right;">Acct. ID</div></th>` then account id column header is right.

So you can for example also define the column widths as 20%, 10%, 30% etc. and then it would work.

Sidenote: I love DataTables!

Answer (score 0):

First Give the parent element (`<th>`) a `relative` position.
Then define a new class for right-aligned titles and add the class to them like this (I made them red for better view):

```css
.thInner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: -5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font: normal normal 10pt Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

th {
  position: relative;
}

.right {
  right: 0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table style="width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <th><div class="thInner right">Acct. ID</div></th>
                <th><div class="thInner">Account Name</div></th>
                <th><div class="thInner">Account Code</div></th>
                <th><div class="thInner right">Sort Code</div></th>
                <th><div class="thInner">Account Number</div></th>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the position of the related container to relative and then the inner heading to absolute so it align wrt the container div.

```
    .thInner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: -5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font: normal normal 10pt Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
th{
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: This answer does not meet what OP's ask.